# nuget overwrite files

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

Is it possible to force nuGet packages to overwrite existing files? I need a nice way of applying patches (files, dll, resources) across 3  similar projects and through that this could be a nice solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be accomplished with powershell and a package dependencies...

I have a NuGet package that I create for ASP.NET MVC it has all the files that I want to add to the standard Mvc project (DisplayTemplates, EditorTemplate, Extensions, BaseController, etc). Let say its called "Company.WebMvc"

I created another NuGet package called "Company.WebMvc-Prep" That has an Install.ps1 script that deletes anything I don't want from the standard Mvc project. Here is an code example of deleting the existing Scripts files...

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

#Remove Script Files

$scripts = $project.ProjectItems | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Scripts" }

if ($scripts) {

    $scripts.ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $_.Delete() }

}
```

I then make "Company.WebMvc-Prep" a dependency of "Company.WebMvc". Why? because Install.ps1 (normally) is run after NuGet adds the files from the content folder. I need it to delete the files first then add the new ones. So when you call...

Install-Package Company.WebMvc

Company.WebMvc-Prep is installed first because it is a dependency (runs Install.ps1)

Then Company.WebMvc is installed which adds your content.

Long and short of it is... You **Can** overwrite existing content on your project via a NuGet package.

P.S. Remember you can also you partial classes to isolate NuGet package code vs. project specific code.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It's exactly what I was looking for. Hadn't thought about the dependency route. This also ensures that I explicitly state which files need removing and updating which is less prone to error.

Comment: I tried this kind of solution, however in my case, every time a new version of the package is installed, I want to delete old files and put new files in place. This requires me to update the version Prep package everytime the main package is updated... I was wondering if I could avoid this.

Answer (score 5):

Overwriting content files isn't supported today.

Comment: Any idea if/when? We would like to use nuget to assist with the distribution/sync of a shared (third party) config we depend on. It would be slick if <file/> had an attribute such overwrite="true", or something similar. This way we could be particular about which files we allow to be overwritten (the default behavior being as it is now.) If there's already a codeplex issue for this I've missed it.

Comment: If there isn't you should add one

Comment: Could you i ask if there's an update allowing overwriting content files ?

Comment: I am also looking for an update, I would like a file in the content file to just be ignored if it already exists as the package pulls in a default template to be customized and I would not want to blow out their changes.

Answer (score 4):

As David Fowler suggest in this discussion
http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/252305
you can deploy your files in a temp folder and then overwrite them at the original location by using PowerShell script.

Answer (score 1):

Although you apparently can't specify this for all installs of the package (according to the other answers), it is actually possible to specify it for a single install. Install the package with:

```
Install-Package com.company.mypackage -FileConflictAction Overwrite
```

This will automatically overwrite all files that conflict during the install process.

Comment: Thanks for idea, but it doesn't work for me. According to [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-update-package) -FileConflictAction will be applied to files referenced in the project. Unfortunately that is not my case.