# Nuget not updating content files which are not included in the csproj file when installing new version of package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I made a nuget package for internal usage which addes a dll and a few javascript/css/html files.

The first time I install it all files are copied but when I create a new version with updated content files, these are not updated.

In the install log I get this during the uninstall of the old version:

```
Removed package 'Consilium.NuTranslation.0.1.1-alpha' from 'packages.config'
Directory 'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\views' is not empty. Skipping...
Directory 'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\js' is not empty. Skipping...
Directory 'App_Plugins\NuTranslation' is not empty. Skipping...
Directory 'App_Plugins\NuTranslation' is not empty. Skipping...
Directory 'App_Plugins\NuTranslation' is not empty. Skipping...
```

And I get this while installing the new version:

```
'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\views\translationHistory.html' already exists. Skipping...
'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\views\sendforTranslation.html' already exists. Skipping...
'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\views\manualTranslationImport.html' already exists. Skipping...
'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\package.manifest' already exists. Skipping...
'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\js\translationHistory.controller.js' already exists. Skipping...
'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\js\sendForTranslation.controller.js' already exists. Skipping...
'App_Plugins\NuTranslation\js\manualTranslationImport.controller.js' already exists. Skipping...
Added package 'Consilium.NuTranslation.0.1.4' to 'packages.config'
```

I just want to point out that those files are not into the csproj file, but they are just inside the folder. I tried adding them to the project file and everything gets updated.

Is there a way to force the update of those files even without adding them to the project?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Seems that you have no options. Nuget [won't replace content files](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2013/12/09/nuget-package-restore-misconceptions.aspx). You can find some ideas that to do in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100410/nuget-overwrite-files). For example you can use FileConflictAction option - it will work only if you reference content files in your project.

```
Update-Packate my.package -FileConflictAction Overwrite
```

But seems that all of that ideas are not about your case.